# What are the risks of targeting Steam, XBLA and PSN for game releases?

Tags: xbox360, steam, playstation3, xbox-live, playstation4

Say that I spend 6-12 months working on a game, submit it to Steam, XBLA, and PSN and I get rejected. Does that mean I just wasted 6-12 months for nothing? Seems like a really big risk in my opinion.

I need to know this because I'm planning to start a game for consoles and PC really soon, and I want to know the risks.

Comment: General PC is much easier than trying for the console market, particularly if you're independently working on small games. Bear in mind though that you still need to match a lot of different PCs but at least they wont all be low powered and the resolution is less restricted.

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a big hosting platform. You could probably host game files on your own.

Comment: You absolutely can make a PC game without Steam. Minecraft is a well known example (and created mainly by one person, at the beginning, too!). Note that I'm a technical person not a businessy person so I don't know how it affects how likely people are to buy your game.

Comment: If you're wondering why the negative votes, it is probably because your question sounds a lot like ranting and whining.

Comment: Also, the amount of time spent on a project really doesn't matter. What's important for the publishers is the end result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm a professional PC / console game developer and many of my friends have moved to mobile game dev because its easier to make money there.  Also, regarding getting the game working at different aspect ratios, there's lots of similar work when doing PC game Dev since each machine can be vastly different. Your other points make sense to me though.  As an independent game developer, who hasn't shipped a PC or console game before its going to be difficult getting a console company to accept your game unfortunately.  You basically have to prove to them you have the background to make it happen which basically means that you've shipped a PC / console game before.  Console Dev has a lot of rules too about how your game has to work and behave in specific situations. It can be a tedious pain to make your game conform.  It also costs significant amounts of money to submit a game (tens of thousands of dollars).  As far as PC games, steam is probably not as hard to get accepted in as consoles, but that doesn't mean its easy.  If you can't get accepted by steam, there are other services to release PC games.  They may be leas prestigious and have fewer customers, but they exist and could be a good starting point for you.  If you finish a game and can't find a way to release it, you could try to sell it to another game company to do that work for you of making it ready for a bigger stage.  Lastly, worst case scenario, once you finish your game you'll have a strong portfolio item for getting into PC/ console game Dev professionally.  For what its worth I've done mobile game dev too and also was not a fan (:  keep chasing what you are after, you'll get there eventually!